# Assign calculated value to variable within generator expression?

Tags: python, generator

a short question: is it possible to assign the result of a calculation within a generator expression to a referrer?

Let's assume I have an expression like this:

`m = (float(i.dist) - float(base) for i in met_obj if str(i.code) != '90')`

`i.dist` is an attribute of an object which I want to chance. I tried:

`m = (float(i.dist) -= float(base) for i in met_obj if str(i.code) != '90')`

Or would I need to use a generator instead?

Thanks!
LarsVegas

Comment: Question is not very clear... can you please give some example input and output?

Comment: What do you want the generated values to be? Do you want them to equal the 'new' `i.dist` values? Or what?

Comment: I'm looping through different files which basically all hold the same information (e.g. distance from an intersection point). But some are in meters others in real world xy. The data is stored in a class, i.dist is for example an attribute of line i. So want to change the attribute of object `i` like this `i.dist = i.dist - base` if a certain condition is met. To clarify: now `met_obj[0].dist = '126165.26'` should become `met_obj[0].dist = -32.5`. Hope this helps understanding...Cheers

Comment: So you want to set the `dist` of each object `i` but what is the variable `m` used for in your example?

Comment: `m.next()` now returns the calculated dist. But as @Maksym Polshcha pointed out: what I tried to do seems to be impossible. It's not that I can't solve my problem. I was just wondering if it was possible and if so how. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short answer: no, it is not possible.

Comment: I asked for a short answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to destructively update objects in a loop, then use a loop, not a generator expression:

```
for i in met_obj if str(i.code) != '90':
   i.dist -= float(base)
```

Generator expressions are useful when programming in a [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) style, while doing assignments to existing variables/members is typically an imperative construct.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. As I said earlier: I was wondering if:-) But honestly it wasn't the best approach anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks there is an error in your code.

As you can see, `float()` is a function, and   the statement `float(i.dist) -= float(base)` means assigning to function call, so it will be a syntax error :)

Comment: I think he knows there is a mistake because he tried that and it didnt work so he is asking here. He is looking for a solution to the problem that is the correct version of his code.

Comment: @wyk actually `float` is a class (or type), not a function, initialize `float()` creates a new instance of `float` which in the op's case would not allow him to edit the intended object.